# Quick Question Regarding Unbounded Sets and its Subsequences

Tags: analysis

If a set is not bounded, does it hold that there exists a sequence contained in the set that is also unbounded?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ we can find an $x_n$ in the set such that $|x_n|>n$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Assume 'unbounded' here means at least 'has no maximum element'.  Pick any value v in the set and define $x_1$ = v.  Since the set has no maximum element, there is a value w in the set such that v < w; define $x_2$ = w.  Define $x_3$, $x_4$, ..., similarly; the result is an unbounded sequence.

If 'unbounded' means 'has no minimum element', the construction is essentially the same, except you keep picking new values smaller each time.  If 'unbounded' means 'has no maximum AND no minimum element', you can 'interleave' the two constructions, i.e start anywhere then alternate between picking a new value larger than the prior largest and picking a new value smaller than the prior smallest.

Comment: This is false, such sequence may not be unbounded. Take $x_n = (1+\frac1n)^n$. It is an increasing sequence but it converges to $e$.